# Парсинг value из input, добавленного при помощи appendChild

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Со страницы нужно спарсить `value` из элемента `input`, который добавлен на страницу

```
function E(a, b, c) {
    if(a.elements[b]) a.elements[b].value = c;
    else {
        var n = U.createElement("input");
        n.type = "hidden";
        n.name = b;
        n.value = c;
        a.appendChild(n)
    }
}
```

JS-код довольно запутан для затруднения парсинга.
Пытался решить проблему при помощи phantomJS

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'URL';

page.open(url, function(status) {
    page.injectJs('/home/user/jquery.js');

    var v = page.evaluate(function() {
        return $('input[name=lkey]').val();
    });

    console.log(v);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Но в ответ просто приходит `null`
Что ещё можно придумать для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Вы использовали phantomJS для того чтобы просто получить value?

Comment: @Khipster по крайней мере попытался

Comment: А вы исключаете, что значение `input[name=lkey]` и есть `null`. Ваш код работает правильно. А мои эксперименты показали, что выражение `$('input[name=lkey]').val()` вернет `null`, только если оно было установлено в `null`.

Comment: @Dmitry да, при отслеживании заголовков (запрос POST) видно, что оно имеет значение, не равное null

Answer (score 0):

Причина описанного явления в том, что сразу после открытия страницы фантомом, искомого элемента на странице еще нет. Поэтому return $('input[name=lkey]').val(); возвращает undefined, который на выходе из page.evaluate превращается в null.

Для решения данной проблемы надо ждать, пока элемент появится на странице.
Здесь приведен [Пример функции-ожидателя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546979/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-phantomjs-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F/582175#582175)