# Как обновить документ в Phantomjs после совершения действия?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Я хочу собрать всю информацию из определённой категории при одном обращении к Phantomjs (пройтись по постраничной навигации, переключаясь по страницам). Дело в том, что сайт при нажатии на номер страницы/стрелочку изменяет целевой блок с информацией и URL страницы через ajax, т.е. перегрузки страницы не происходит. Phantomjs это не понимает и продолжает брать информацию с изначально загруженной страницы.

Вариант прогонять несколько раз page.open с изменением URL - не очень хороший, слишком долго будет загружать и нагрузка слишком большая выйдет.

Примерный код:

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
    var data = page.evaluate(function() {
        //Пока стрелка вправо активна, нажимаем на неё
        while ($('.arrow_right').hasClass('disabled') === false) {
            //Логика сбора данных

            //Нажимаем на стрелку
            var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
            document.querySelector('.arrow_right').dispatchEvent(ev);

            //Так подозреваю, что здесь что-то надо сделать для обновления данных
        }
    });

    console.log(data);

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Ссылка вида site.ru/category/page/1/

Подскажите, есть ли вообще такая возможность или нет?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы решить эту задачу, вы можете ждать требуемого состояния, пока данные на странице не обновятся, проверяя это условие, например, каждые 50 миллисекунд. Ниже приведен пример реализации такой функции-ожидателя с использованием промисов Q:

```
var Q = require('q');

var currentUrl = page.url;
waitState(function urlChanged() {  // ждем смены урла 
    return page.url !== currentUrl;
}).then(function() {
    // будет выполнено, когда дождались состояния смены урла
})

function waitState(state, timeout) {
    console.log('Старт ожидания состояния ' + state.name);

    var limitTime = timeout * 1000 || 20000;
    var startTime = new Date();

    return wait();

    function wait() {
        return Q()
            .then(function() {
                if (state()) {
                    console.log('Дождались состояния ' + state.name);
                    return;
                } else if (new Date() - startTime > limitTime) {
                    var errorMessage = 'Таймаут ожидания состояния ' + state.name;
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                    throw new Error(errorMessage);
                } else {
                    return Q.delay(50).then(wait);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                throw error;
            })
        ;
    }
}
```